# How to accomplish numbered paragraphs with increased margin?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec, article

When I make a parenthetical remark in my document, I like to give it larger margins and smaller text. I've been doing this via `addmargin` in the `scrextend` package, and just writing `\footnotesize` to change the text size.

I also like numbering many of my paragraphs with subsubsection numbers, and such that there is no line skipped after the subsubsection number. I've accomplished this by using `titleformat` inside the `titlesec` package.

Now when I do a parenthetical remark, I'd like to number this also. But I've found that `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph`, etc. do not work inside `addmargin`.

The optimal thing would be that indented sections are suborned by numbering to the subsubsection above them (so they are numbered `paragraph`s).

> Question: How can I accomplish a numbered, indented paragraph with
>   smaller text?

(Could I perhaps jimmy with the margin via `titleformat`, and abandon `addmargin` altogether?)

Here's what I have

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,top=1in, bottom=1in, right=1in, left=.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat
{\subsubsection} % command
[runin] % shape
{\normalfont\bfseries} % format
{\bf{\thesubsubsection.}} % label
{1.2ex} % sep
{} % before-code
[.
] % after-code

\begin{document}
\section{Free Functors}
\subsection{Categories With Models}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Blah Blah Blah}
\blindtext

\vskip .3cm
\begin{addmargin}{1.5em}
\footnotesize
\textbf{Example.} Nevertheless, \blindtext

\blindtext
\end{addmargin}
\vskip .3cm

\subsubsection{More Stuff}
\blindtext

\vskip .3cm
\begin{addmargin}{1.5em}
\footnotesize
\textbf{Caveat.} And yet, \blindtext

\blindtext
\end{addmargin}
\vskip .3cm
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
\newenvironment{remark}[1][]%
   {\refstepcounter{paragraph}%
    \list{}{\leftmargin=1.5em\rightmargin=\leftmargin}\item[]%
    \footnotesize
    {\bfseries \theparagraph. #1}\ 
   }%
   {\endlist%
   }
```

This environment increases both margins by 1.5em and uses the `paragraph` counter. The optional argument is used to add a label.

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
... code from above ...
\begin{document}
\section{Free Functors}
\subsection{Categories With Models}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{Blah Blah Blah}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{remark}[Example]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this. I added two (and another) version of the paragraph styles you were looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\titleformat
{\subsubsection} % command
[runin] % shape
{\normalfont\bfseries} % format
{\bf{\thesubsubsection.}} % label
{1.2ex} % sep
{} % before-code
[. ] % after-code

\newtheoremstyle{labled}{0pt}{0pt}{}{}{\bfseries}{.}{0.5em}{}

\theoremstyle{labled}
\newtheorem{numberedspecialsection}[subsubsection]{}
\newtheorem{subspecialsection}{}[subsubsection]

\newenvironment{numberedspecial}{\vskip .3cm
\begin{addmargin}{1.5em}
\footnotesize
\begin{numberedspecialsection}\textbf}{\end{numberedspecialsection}\end{addmargin}
\vskip .3cm
}

\newenvironment{subsubsubsection}{\vskip .3cm
\begin{addmargin}{1.5em}
\footnotesize
\begin{subspecialsection}\textbf}{\end{subspecialsection}\end{addmargin}
\vskip .3cm
}

\newenvironment{plainspecial}{\vskip .3cm
\begin{addmargin}{1.5em}
\footnotesize
\textbf}{\end{addmargin}
\vskip .3cm
}

\begin{document}
\section{Free Functors}
\subsection{Categories With Models}
\blindtext
\subsubsection{Blah Blah Blah}
\blindtext

\begin{subsubsubsection}{Example.}
Nevertheless, \blindtext

\blindtext
\end{subsubsubsection}


\begin{numberedspecial}{More Example.}
By the way, \blindtext

\blindtext
\end{numberedspecial}


\subsubsection{More Stuff}

\blindtext

\begin{plainspecial}{Caveat.} 
And yet, \blindtext

\blindtext
\end{plainspecial}

\end{document}
```

It is will solve what you need! :)

[image]